# Can self-discharge cause a Li-ion battery to swell?

Tags: battery

Suppose a Li-ion battery, with a polymer electrolyte, is left unused for a few years with no load connected. Can self-discharge alone during this time cause any gassing in the the battery?
If yes, can this make the battery physically swollen?

Comment: It is my **opinion** well designed and manufactured Li-ion battery will not swell under conditions described above. The key here is work purchase batteries from reputable sources. Additionally issues like swelling also can occur due to poor system design. Repeat, Li-ion batteries used per the manufactures guidelines are safe.

Comment: Nevertheless, this was a problem in the past. It was a big problem. We were buying liquid nitrogen by the rail car to freeze the things and make them safe to remove and transport. Years later I heard that they just decided to keep them frozen for about ten years and figured they'd be dead by then. This was in the '90s, and I believe it was the first commercial use of Lion batteries ever.

Comment: The program began in 1978, apparently. https://minutemanmissile.com/lowerlauncherequipmentroom.html